# MYSQL issue selecting and sorting from separate tables

Tags: mysql, select, join

I am having difficulty assembling the proper sql statements to list and sort data based upon my needs. Below is the structure of two tables I need to select data from.

For each user in the users table, I need to list id, name, and key[a] and key[b] from users_nfo table.

```
Table users: 
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  | aa   |
| 2  | bb   |
| 3  | cc   |
| 4  | dd   |
| 5  | ee   |
+----+------+

Table users_nfo:
+----+-----+-----+-------+
| id | uid | key | value |
+----+-----+-----+-------+
| 1  | 1   | a   | 22    |
| 2  | 1   | b   | 47    |
| 3  | 2   | a   | 38    |
| 4  | 2   | b   | 16    |
| 5  | 3   | a   | 27    |
| 6  | 3   | b   | 67    |
| 7  | 4   | a   | 75    |
| 8  | 4   | b   | 67    |
| 9  | 5   | a   | 63    |
| 10 | 5   | b   | 67    |
+----+-----+-----+-------+
```

The result should be similar to this

```
Array result: 
+----+------+---+---+
| id | name | a | b |
+----+------+---+---+
| 1  | aa   |22 |47 |
| 2  | bb   |38 |16 |
| 3  | cc   |27 |67 |
| 4  | dd   |75 |67 |
| 5  | ee   |63 |67 |
+----+------+---+---+
```

Additionally, I need to be able to sort by any column key, such as sorted asc by b.

Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to join the users_nfo (sic) table twice, and include the `key` column in the join condition. Like this:

```
SELECT u.ID, u.name, n1.value, n2.value from USERS u
JOIN users_nfo n1
ON u.id = n1.id AND n1.key = 'a'
JOIN users_nfo n2
ON u.id = n2.id AND n1.key = 'b'
ORDER BY n2.value ASC
```

Comment: the problem with storing values like this is that for the generic case you will ofcourse need a configurable amount of joins which is not nice. So you will have to first fetch the user, then the attributes.

Comment: and if you only have a limited amount of attributes, they can as well be columns.

Comment: If you're doing the query from a programming language, it can create all the dynamic joins on the fly, after first doing `select distinct key from users_nfo`.

Comment: Actually, I am using PHP and WordPress. I'm selecting data from the wp_users table and wp_usermeta table to display in a list. Not having much luck yet.